# Защита от спама - достаточно ли включить JS?

Tags: php, javascript, бот

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой множественных регистраций ботов. До этого форма регистрации была не очень совершенна (однако использовала JS для подгрузки данных, без JS вообще нельзя было бы зарегистрироваться) - я ее улучшил и все сделал без использования JS вообще. Ну и боты начали регистрироваться (капчу не ставил).

Вот тут и вопрос - получается, что боты JS не могут выполнять? Ну или по крайней мере большинство? Достаточна ли такая мера как наличие JS у пользователя?

Если нет  - то тогда надо значить капчу делать. Может ли кто посоветовать на php какой нибудь модуль несложной капчи?

Comment: Гуглить "защита от спама". И не используйте напрягаемую юзеров капчу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможности спам-машины зависит от многих факторов:

- Это модуль в трояне? Тогда JS-движок туда не засунешь, только что-то
  попроще, `JS`-проверка защитит наверняка.
- Это прога на абузном деде с кучей носков? Тогда конечно
  можно и движок приделать, и совершенней и быстрее обновить код можно.
- Это индивидуальный комплекс, написанный за $50.000? Обойдёт всё, от
  человека разве что по содержанию отличишь. Постфактум, разумеется.
- etc.

---

В целом, проверка на JS достаточно хороша, хотя сейчас спамеры адаптируются к этой защите (расковырять и подключить `PhantomJS`, например).
Пользователей с отключённым JS не так много наверное (совсем параноики под виртуалкой сидят), так что для них просто вывешивать красивый баннер в тэге `<noscript></noscript>`.
Делать простейшую проверку через `JS` на `submit` (валидация, например, всегда нужна) и/или загружать формы без `action`, а после загрузки тем же `JS` ставить его на место из `data-action`.

Answer (score 1):

не думаю что достаточно только js. вот тут интересная статья по поводу как обойтись без капчи - они ж реально напрягают... https://habrahabr.ru/post/151084/
плюс у пользователя может быть отключен js - валидацию обязательно надо делать и на стороне бэкенда.